# Oracle best way to set create/modify user vua a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I recall reading an article or seeing a video  from an oracle expert regarding setting create_user or modify_user using a trigger.  I wish I could remember more details!!

There was a recommendation to use the sys_context command to get the value.

I know of the following commands(see below). As I'm dealing with sensitive data, which command who provide me with the most secure way to capture the data I need? I suspect it would be OS_USER to change that would require a person who knows the root password to edit /etc/sudoers.

I would like to get some other opinions. In addition, if anyone remembers the link to the INSERT/UPDATE trigger can you please post it. I believe it was a before each row trigger, but I am unsure

sys_context('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')

sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')

sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER')

Comment: Please, describe your requirement, not the solution you've seen. You may use [centralized authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-FD72C458-E250-46D3-84B6-FF3F34CDAC5D) of your users to keep it "more secure".

Comment: Be careful using USERENV sys_context variables for security purposes. Almost all of them (all but PROXY_USER) can be spoofed by a savvy Java programmer. Most necessary changes to user accounts can be handled with built in policy/user profiles, not triggers. I agree with astentx: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @astenx I have some secure data and I want to add columns create_user, modify_user via a trigger. I'm looking for the most secure ways to capture those values.

Comment: One more time, with emphasis:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example